# How to call external Javascript function which is in separate file under assets folder in Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, tsconfig

[image]

[image]

```
//Way 1 - Not working
import { LoadCarouselAndPopup } from '../../../assets/js/main.js';
LoadCarouselAndPopup();

//Way 2 - Not working
declare var System: any;
System.import('../../../assets/js/main.js')
    .then(xJS => {
        xJS.LoadCarouselAndPopup();
    });
```

}

I have tried above two ways.

In first way, I cant compile the code because it throwing error like "error TS5055: Cannot write file 'main.js' because it would overwrite input file". In this case i have added "allowJs: true" also.

In way 2, I got error like "cannot read property 'call' of undefined"..

Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using angular-cli, try adding it to your angular-cli scripts array. This will load the script into the browser.

Answer (score 2):

As I have seen you folder structure in images I believe that you are using angular-cli for this, so you can include your external scripts by including the path of that scripts in **.angular-cli.json** file in scripts array

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "dummy-project"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": ['assets/filename.js],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are using angular cli. You have load your script in the cliconfig. 
Here is the wiki how you can accomplish: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts